# Icono de aplicacion en status bar

Tags: android, android-studio

Estimados, como puedo dejar el icono de mi app en status bar cuando esta queda corriendo en segundo plano?, mi app utiliza la clase MediaPlayer para reproducir un streaming y esto quiero dejarlo en status bar con algún icono.

Comment: [Esto](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-android-media-style-notifications-with-media-session-controls/165) quizas te puede ayudar (Ingles).

Comment: pero ahí se refieren a la pantalla de bloqueo, es lo mismo?

Comment: Pues, puede que sí, puede que no, si necesitas un icono en el area de notificaciones, creo que puede aplicar el mismo caso, sólo te he pasado el link para que pienses una forma de implementarlo.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es iniciar un [servicio en "primer plano"](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) (foreground), de esta manera el mismo android te va a pedir una notificación para mostrarle al usuario que este servicio se esta ejecutando en primer plano y por lo tanto tiene prioridad para el uso de recursos. Esta notificación NO se puede eliminar hasta que el servicio haya terminado.

Comment: Crear un servicio y dentro de ello reproduce el sonido, ahi tenes un ejemplo como poner un servicio en primer plano (Esto para que veas el progreso del audio si en caso de que desees)
http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/07/tutorial-para-crear-un-servicio-en-android/